# Javascript editor (tinymce) in sharepoint online (office 365)

Tags: javascript, html-editor, popup

I'm trying to add a editor on my EditForm.aspx. I'm using [Tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/) for this. Importing works fine. Also adding it to a textarea. But when I click a button in this editor, and a popup SHOULD appear with more options, I get a message to download the popup on the client instead of just showing it. Anyone who knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by renaming the html-files linked to the buttons to an .aspx instead of a html. By doing this, I get my popup and everything works perfect again!